# How to configure WCF end-to-end logging?

Tags: wcf, logging, msmq, certificate

I have a problem that I'd like to solve, but I don't know how to configure end-to-end logging in WCF (I'm not sure I can solve my problem even with end-to-end logging enabled). I have three applications (A, B, C) that use WCF service through NetMsmqBinding to communicate with each other. A is the host, and B and C are clients of the WCF service. The service uses message security with certificates. The communication between B and A works perfectly OK, though, the communication between C and A does not. So I'd like to use logging and figure out why the messages are deleted from the queue (in the case C -> A) and are not processed by the host... How do we configure logging for this scenario in order to diagnose the problem... (app B and app C are on the same machine, app A is on a different machine). (B -> A works both with and without certificates) (C -> A works ONLY without certificates). I need to configure C -> A to work with certificates, but I don't know what's wrong in order to fix it. Please help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to do WCF end-to-end tracing:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa738749.aspx

In your case I would have used Enterprise Library Logging. Logged entry and exit of each method with which parameters were sent, as well as using try catch around critical parts of the code, with logging of the exception.

Hope this helps.